# save wording, save as? save new?

Tags: web-app, save

We have a situation where a user would be working on a shared document. If they edit that document they may want to save it in a shared state, or fork the document. The question is how to word it.

I've heard the convention for the web is `Save New`, but this is questionable. This is a web app and I am not sure `Save As` in intuitive in this context as there is no real traditional file system available to the user.

Are there any studies on this topic? Is `Save As` the right convention for the web? Is there a better way this could be handled?

We definitely need a distinction between saving the shared version and saving a fork.

Comment: Is this a technical audience where you could use the phrasing "Fork"?

Comment: no, unfortunately 'Fork' wont work.

Comment: @AthomSfere - you could provided there is no [overzealous, foul-mouthed autocorrection](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39837/should-autocorrect-include-swear-words-out-of-the-box). Seriously, what about "Save a personal copy"?

Comment: I don't know that I've ever seen "save new" but I have seen "save a copy" on the web pretty frequently

Comment: I've seen and used the following "Save a Copy" "Duplicate" "Clone"

Answer (score 7):

**To most people, there is no clear distinction between a web-app, website, or application** in terms of how they understand interfaces and instructions.

"Save As" has been used in the most common applications for decades, and I have yet to see anyone confused by it.  The situation that you describe is exactly one where "Save As" would be appropriate, and so **use "Save As"**.

With issues like this, it's always worth doing some user testing, which doesn't have to be formal and time consuming.  You can do some quick and dirty testing with a few people to get an idea of whether or not this is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

"Save As" will probably be fine.

May I offer up "Save duplicate" or "Save a copy" since multiple users are touching the document. This may better send the message that this new save will be a branch and not affect the original.